# Word or phrase expressing that it's ok to deal with personal things at work

Tags: travail

Years ago, on a radio program, I heard a discussion about how the French have a word (or phrase) that describes the phenomena where it's ok for people to take care of personal needs at work because it understood that time that will be made up by doing work items at home.

In other words, everybody thinks about and solves work problems at home so using work time to do personal chores at work is justified.

Does any one know what that word or phrase is which describes this practice?

Comment: I have no idea what this could be. Do you remember if it's supposed to be a formal or informal term? A legal term? Specifically about being ok to use work time for personal things, or work resources as well? Specifically about being ok to use work time for personal things, or about time leaking in both directions?

Comment: I really not sure if it's formal or informal, but if I had to guess I'd say informal? But this sounds familiar "time leaking in both directions" Maybe it's that.

Comment: Was the expression describing the practice or illustrating the "it goes both ways" idea i.e. like ["donnant-donnant"](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donnant-donnant)? Something qualifying the workplace/person in context i.e. soho/télétravailleur? Something focusing on the equality between the work done at home vs. office i.e. parité, équivalence?

Comment: I think it was more like describing the practice, that there is a sense of equality between work done at home makes up for personal time taken at work.

Comment: In English, this would be covered by the term "work-life balance".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been French 49 years now. And I have no idea what you could possibly refer to. Are you certain that such word/expression exists in the French language? Where or in what context have heard it mentioned first?

Comment: After posting this question and reading all the responses, I'm not certain any more. I'm 51 and I understand that the memory is a highly fallible resource...

Comment: But now I'm a Francophone from France. Other Francophone countries such Belgium, Switzerland, Quebec might use something like you describe and I wouldn't know...

Answer (score 2):

S'occuper ou prendre soin de ses affaires personnelles au travail. Il s'agit là d'une tolérance. L'employeur ne peut attendre en retour que le salarié travaille à la maison en échange de cette tolérance.

I hope I can help dismiss the myth of reciprocal favours outlined in the question as this is a matter of rights clearly spelled by the law.

The highest French court "cour de cassation" ruled an employee may phone, surf the net or send private emails during work hours.

As a matter of fact an employer may not read personal emails identified as such either sent from work or from a work computer.

"L’employeur ne peut pas s’immiscer dans les affaires personnelles de ses salariés. Sauf si celles-ci empiètent de manière abusive sur la vie de l’entreprise."

"Un salarié peut-il surfer sur Internet, téléphoner ou envoyer des e-mails personnels pendant ses horaires de travail ?

Oui, mais à condition de le faire de manière modérée, c’est-à-dire sans que cela n’empêche le salarié d’effectuer correctement le travail pour lequel il est payé. En cas d’abus, l’employeur peut sanctionner le salarié, y compris par un licenciement pour faute grave (Cour de cassation, chambre sociale, 26 février 2013, pourvoi n° 11-27372).

De même, il est permis au salarié d’utiliser son téléphone professionnel à des fins personnelles. Mais là encore, tout est une question de mesure. L’utilisation doit rester limitée à des appels d’une durée raisonnable."

Les e-mails identifiés comme personnel, stockés sur l’ordinateur de travail ou reçus sur la messagerie de travail sont qualifiés de correspondance privée et ne peuvent à ce titre être consultés par l’employeur, même en présence du salarié (Cour de cassation, chambre sociale, 18 octobre 2006, pourvoi n° 04-48025 et Cour de cassation, chambre sociale 19 juin 2013 n°12-12.138).

https://saisirprudhommes.com/fiches-prudhommes/la-vie-privee-et-personnelle-du-salarie

Answer (score 1):

I think you might refer to the expression "laisser-faire les choses".
You can find references to this meaning 
here
http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/laisser-faire
and here
http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/laisser/45967/locution?q=laisser-faire#163295.

The first link defines it well from past experience since French is my first language.
It defines it as

> fait de laisser se dérouler une action bien que l'on soit conscient
>   des risques encourus par la personne effectuant cette action

which translates to

> letting someone do something even with the knowledge of the risks the
>   person is subject to

It implies that person 1 trusts person 2 to carry the right tasks or duties.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Après quelques recherches, j'ai trouvé les expressions "**mesure(s) de conciliation travail-famille**" ou "**mesure(s) de conciliation travail-vie privée**".

Ces mesures peuvent être mises en place par l'employeur afin que l'employer concilie plus facilement sa vie professionnelle et sa vie privée. Elles peuvent par exemple prendre les formes suivantes:

- envisager des adaptations ou des facilitations quant à la prise
  du congé de maternité, du congé-éducation payé, du congé parental, du
  crédit-temps, du congé prévu pour prendre soin d’une personne
  dépendante (assistance médicale, soins palliatifs) ;
- envisager de conclure une convention collective d’entreprise pour étendre le crédit-temps à cinq ans (plutôt qu’un an) ;
- rémunérer les jours de congé pour raisons impérieuses et d’allaitement ;
- faciliter les changements de régime de travail tout au long de la carrière ;
- permettre l’accès à des services de garde d’enfants qui soient de qualité, abordables, et compatibles avec les horaires de travail (y
  compris pendant les périodes de vacances scolaires) ;
- développer une culture d’entreprise qui facilite les modalités de conciliation entre vie professionnelle et familiale (exemples :
  valoriser le fait que les hommes prennent soin de leur famille et
  demandent un congé parental, favoriser le remplacement des
  travailleurs en congé quel que soit le type de congé, répartir la
  charge de travail incombant au travailleur absent d’une manière
  équitable et supportable au sein des équipes) ;
- favoriser les aménagements de temps de travail : horaires décalés, temps partiel, semaine comprimée à 4 jours, annualisation du
  temps de travail (variation des horaires sur l’année) ;
- mettre en place un horaire avec des plages pour débuter et terminer la journée de travail ;
- proposer des modalités de travail facilitant la conciliation « emploi-famille » telles que le télétravail.

Donc pourquoi pas également permettre au travailleur de prendre un certain temps durant ses heures de travail afin de s'occuper d'affaires familiales ou privées, et inversement, par conciliation, par tolérance d'une certaine flexibilité.

Sources:

- http://www.abbet.be/Fiche-6-1-1-Concilier-vie-privee
- http://www.travailfamille.com/
- http://www.canalvie.com/sante-beaute/bien-etre/articles-bien-etre/la-conciliation-travail-famille-1.959989
- http://tclcf.qc.ca/files/guide-conciliation-travail-famille-tclcf.pdf (Voir page 11 pour voir les mesures informelles existantes et les pages suivantes pour les solutions)

Comment: Non, « conciliation travail-vie privée », c'est un terme qui couvre des dispositifs légaux ou contractuels (horaires flexibles, congés, télétravail, etc.), et qui n'inclut pas du tout le mélange d'activités personnelles et professionnelles.

Comment: @Gilles: I do think it's relevant though.

Answer (score 1):

I would say: "Il faut bien que tout se fasse". (french expression)

Meaning that things need to be done, whatever the place or the time.

Answer (score 0):

In English, [ROWE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROWE) is the [copyrighted acronym](http://gorowe.com/pages/the-creators) for “[Results-Only Work Environment](http://www.theproductivitypro.com/FeaturedArticles/article00114.htm),” which I’ve seen translated into French as: « [Environnement de travail axé uniquement sur les résultats](http://www.wedemain.fr/Quatre-initiatives-qui-vont-vous-changer-la-vie-au-bureau_a591.html) » (I haven’t found an acronym for the French version).

Such a work environment (and management style) is based on the concept that: “*Work* is (or should be) **a thing that one does** rather than **a place where one goes**” (« Le travail n’est plus un lieu où l’on se rend mais quelque chose que l’on fait, peu importe le lieu et le moment »), and it calls for flexibility BOTH:

1) in permitting/encouraging more work done while away from the traditional “work place” (at home, for example) AND

2) in permitting/encouraging more personal, non-work-related tasks done while at the traditional “work place,” including, without limitation, "INTRApreneurial" (INTRAprenantes) pursuits.

This ROWE concept dates from around 2008, so if "years ago" means before that, then the term/phrase/concept that you remember is probably something else, but if the radio program was post-2008, then perhaps:

> **Environnement de travail axé uniquement sur les résultats**

is the phrase/concept that you seek.